# SAS Enterprise Guide using 1 query on multiple data sets

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to run multiple data sets (that are in the same format) through a single query and for it to produce an output for each data set that is input.

Is the possible in SAS Enterprise Guide?

Answer (score 1):

For most tasks in EG, you can right-click them and choose "Select Input Data...", and change the input data. The filter & query task, which I'm assuming you're talking about, does not have this option.

The only approaches I can think of to re-use a query involve delving into SAS code. If you're comfortable with this, here's one suggestion (this is in EG4.1, I presume later versions are similar):

1. Create your desired query from your
   first data set using the filter and
   query task.
2. Save & close the filter & query dialog.
3. Right-click the query task and
   select "Add as code template". A new
   code object will appear in the
   project designer. When you open it,
   you'll see the SAS code that was
   built by the filter & query task.
4. In here, change the input data (it
   will be in the `from` clause of the
   SQL code) to a different input data
   set, and change the name of the output data (see
   `create table xxx as`). You may also
   need to change the name of the
   output data where it says
   `%_eg_conditional_dropds(xxx)` or
   similar - this part is dropping a
   dataset with the same name as your
   output data, if it exists.

It's all a bit laborious - if you're doing a lot of this, I suggest you hop into SAS coding, because there are lots of ways to do what you're describing that are much easier than hacking EG task code :)

Answer (score 1):

Write the sas code to loop through the datasets executing the sql on each one and naming the results with a unique identifier. Not fun the in point and click world.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how many datasets you need to run this for at a time but perhaps you could use a dynamic prompt?

[http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.sas.com%2Fresources%2Fpapers%2Fproceedings10%2F041-2010.pdf&ei=khmjTeClJ4iCsQPV7PX5DA&usg=AFQjCNFotS3cbwYl5kCCpQUfqKYK3ndflQ&sig2=3ItVrgWXlegBzvjt4-rGAQ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/041-2010.pdf&ei=khmjTeClJ4iCsQPV7PX5DA&usg=AFQjCNFotS3cbwYl5kCCpQUfqKYK3ndflQ&sig2=3ItVrgWXlegBzvjt4-rGAQ)

Alternatively, attack it from a different angle by appending all of the datasets together then split into the different outputs once you get to the reporting side...